# Showing that two spaces are homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $x_0 \in S^1 \times S^1$. I want to show that $(S^1 \times S^1) - \{x_0\}$ and $S^1 \vee S^1$ are homotopy equivalent.

We have to show that $\exists$ maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f \simeq id_x$ and $f \circ g \simeq id_y$ (with $X = (S^1 \times S^1) - \{x_0\}$ and $Y = S^1 \vee S^1 = S^1 \amalg S^1$).

I want to find continuous functions $f$ and $g$ but cannot think of any. I was just wondering if somebody could give me a hint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $S^1 \times S^1$ as a square with opposite sides identified (this is precisely what you do when considering a torus), then remove a point inside it. It is now easy to construct a deformation retraction onto its boundary, which is $S^1 \vee S^1$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, that *is* what I was doing...but I couldn't figure it out. I wasn't thinking of it as a square...I was thinking of it as a circle (which doesn't really matter, right?). But even when I tried thinking of it as a square, it didn't make any difference. I will edit my question and post a picture to clarify what I'm thinking, ok?

Comment: Your picture isn't correct.. try to google "torus square identification"

Comment: http://motls.blogspot.it/2013/04/shapes-of-torus-and-modular-group.html           the first picture: it's completely different from yours, which has nothing to do with a torus

Comment: Oh, maybe I got what you're saying...so are you saying that it is easier to consider it as  a square with opposite sides identified (and a hole inside) rather than thinking of it as a torus with a hole (even though they are basically the same thing of course)...is that what you wanted to say?

Comment: @Pece : I suppose you have added the picture, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. I thought $S^1 \vee S^1$ was the disjoint union of $S^1$ and $S^1$, but its actually two $S^1$'s that share a point, right? However, we see that $(S^1 \times S^1) - x_0$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \vee S^1$...because if we enlarge the hole in the square and identify the sides, we will be getting exactly $S^1 \vee S^1$. So $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, which automatically implies that they are homotopy equivalent. Is that correct?

Comment: $S^1 \vee S^1$ is the pointed sum, as you claimed. But the map you're talking about is not a homeomorphism, it is just a homotopy equivalence: for example if you consider $S^1 \vee S^1 \setminus x$ (where $x$ is the common point) you get a disconnected space, while it is impossible to disconnect the torus minus a point by simply removing a point.

Comment: But is it not possible to keep making $X$ thinner and thinner until there is only one point that connects the two circles? After all, can we not make it as thin as we want? We are not cutting anything while making it thinner...so why wouldn't it be a homeomorphism?

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of homotopy equivalence and that of isomorphism: try to find a map $X \to Y$ which is a homeomorphism (it is impossible, as I pointed out in the previous comment). On the contrary, you are just thinking to an homotopy from $Id_X$ to $i \circ r$, where $r$ is the above mentioned retraction onto $S^1 \vee S^1$.